# error of Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string. when trying to generate gridview

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, datagridview

hye, i'm having problem where when i want to get data for date "4/12/2013 2:00" i will get an error,Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string. but if i search for date "24/11/2013 16:00", i would be able to get the data output. is there anything wrong with my code since i have already create code for which it should have accept a single date in the first code shown below.

```
if (Dayrange.Checked == true)
    {
        if (txtStart1.Text.Length == 10)
        {
            startdate = DateTime.ParseExact(txtStart1.Text, "dd/MM/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
        }
        else if (txtStart1.Text.Length == 9)
        {
            try
            {
                startdate = DateTime.ParseExact(txtStart1.Text, "%d/MM/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
            }
            catch (FormatException e)
            {
                startdate = DateTime.ParseExact(txtStart1.Text, "dd/%M/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
            }
        }
        else if (txtStart1.Text.Length == 8)
        {
            startdate = DateTime.ParseExact(txtStart1.Text, "%d/%M/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
        }

        //check enddate
        if (txtEnd1.Text.Length == 10)
        {
            enddate = DateTime.ParseExact(txtEnd1.Text, "dd/MM/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
        }
        else if (txtEnd1.Text.Length == 9)
        {
            try
            {
                enddate = DateTime.ParseExact(txtEnd1.Text, "%d/MM/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
            }
            catch (FormatException e)
            {
                enddate = DateTime.ParseExact(txtEnd1.Text, "dd/%M/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
            }

        }
        else if (txtEnd1.Text.Length == 8)
        {
            enddate = DateTime.ParseExact(txtEnd1.Text, "%d/%M/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
        }

        //check starttime format
        if (txtStart2.Text.Length == 1)
        {
            starttime = DateTime.ParseExact(txtStart2.Text, "%H", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
        }
        else if (txtStart2.Text.Length == 2)
        {
            starttime = DateTime.ParseExact(txtStart2.Text, "HH", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
        }
        //check endtime format
        if (txtEnd2.Text.Length == 1)
        {
            endtime = DateTime.ParseExact(txtEnd2.Text, "%H", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
        }
        else if (txtEnd2.Text.Length == 2)
        {
            endtime = DateTime.ParseExact(txtEnd2.Text, "HH", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
        }

        Label1.Text = startdate.ToShortDateString();
        Label2.Text = enddate.ToShortDateString();
        Label3.Text = starttime.ToShortTimeString();
        Label4.Text = endtime.ToShortTimeString();
        Label5.Text = startdate.ToShortDateString() + " " + starttime.ToShortTimeString();
        Label6.Text = enddate.ToShortDateString() + " " + endtime.ToShortTimeString();
        Label7.Text = Label5.Text.Length.ToString();
        Label8.Text = Label6.Text.Length.ToString();

        if (Label5.Text.Length == 16)
        {
            combdatetime1 = DateTime.ParseExact(Label5.Text, "dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
        }
        else if (Label5.Text.Length == 15)
        {
            combdatetime1 = DateTime.ParseExact(Label5.Text, "dd/MM/yyyy %H:mm", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
        }

        if (Label6.Text.Length == 16)
        {
            combdatetime2 = DateTime.ParseExact(Label6.Text, "dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
        }
        else if (Label6.Text.Length == 15)
        {
            combdatetime2 = DateTime.ParseExact(Label6.Text, "dd/MM/yyyy %H:mm", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
        }

        Label9.Text = combdatetime1.ToString();
        Label10.Text = combdatetime2.ToShortDateString();
    }
```

here is the code to bind the data to  gridview.

```
if ((Byday.Checked == true) || (Dayrange.Checked == true)) 
    {
        if (((Maxdata.Checked == true) && (curdata.Checked == true)) && ((txtStart2.Text.Length == 0 ) && (txtEnd2.Text.Length == 0)))
        {
            gridmaxdata.Visible = true;
            lblmaxdata.Visible = true;
            lblcurdata.Visible = true;
            gridcurdata.Visible = true;
            lblmaxdata.Text = "Highest Data";
            lblcurdata.Text = "Current Data";
            // ConnectionString to NorthWind Database.
            string connectionString = "Data Source=.\\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=C:\\Users\\shafiq\\Desktop\\history\\App_Data\\Radiation.mdf;Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True";

            // Create SQLDataSource.
            SqlDataSource sqlDataSource = new SqlDataSource();
            sqlDataSource.ID = "SqlDataSource123";
            this.Page.Controls.Add(sqlDataSource);

            // Bind ConnectionString to SQLDataSource.
            sqlDataSource.ConnectionString = connectionString;
            // Retrieve records with only 5 Columns from Employees table of NorthWind Database.
            sqlDataSource.SelectCommand = "SELECT top 30 [date], [data] FROM [loc1] WHERE (([data] >= '2') AND ([date] >= '" + startdate.ToLongDateString() + "') AND ([date] < '" + enddate.ToLongDateString() + "')) ORDER BY [data] DESC, [date] DESC";

            // Bind SQLDataSource to GridView after retrieving the records.
            gridmaxdata.DataSource = sqlDataSource;
            gridmaxdata.DataBind();

            // Create SQLDataSource.
            SqlDataSource sqlDataSource2 = new SqlDataSource();
            sqlDataSource2.ID = "SqlDataSource12";
            this.Page.Controls.Add(sqlDataSource2);

            // Bind ConnectionString to SQLDataSource.
            sqlDataSource2.ConnectionString = connectionString;
            // Retrieve records with only 5 Columns from Employees table of NorthWind Database.
            sqlDataSource2.SelectCommand = "SELECT [date], [data] FROM [loc1] WHERE (([date] >= '" + startdate.ToLongDateString() + "') AND ([date] < '" + enddate.ToLongDateString() + "')) ORDER BY [data] DESC, [date] DESC";

            // Bind SQLDataSource to GridView after retrieving the records.
            gridcurdata.DataSource = sqlDataSource2;
            gridcurdata.DataBind();
        }
        else if (((Maxdata.Checked == true) && (curdata.Checked == true)) && ((txtStart2.Text.Length > 0 ) && (txtEnd2.Text.Length > 0)))
        {
            gridmaxdata.Visible = true;
            lblmaxdata.Visible = true;
            lblcurdata.Visible = true;
            gridcurdata.Visible = true;
            lblmaxdata.Text = "Highest Data";
            lblcurdata.Text = "Current Data";
            // ConnectionString to NorthWind Database.
            string connectionString = "Data Source=.\\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=C:\\Users\\shafiq\\Desktop\\history\\App_Data\\Radiation.mdf;Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True";

            // Create SQLDataSource.
            SqlDataSource sqlDataSource = new SqlDataSource();
            sqlDataSource.ID = "SqlDataSource123";
            this.Page.Controls.Add(sqlDataSource);

            // Bind ConnectionString to SQLDataSource.
            sqlDataSource.ConnectionString = connectionString;
            // Retrieve records with only 5 Columns from Employees table of NorthWind Database.
            sqlDataSource.SelectCommand = "SELECT top 30 [date], [data] FROM [loc1] WHERE (([data] >= '2') AND ([date] >= '" + combdatetime1.ToLongDateString() + "') AND ([date] < '" + combdatetime2.ToLongDateString()+ "')) ORDER BY [data] DESC, [date] DESC";

            // Bind SQLDataSource to GridView after retrieving the records.
            gridmaxdata.DataSource = sqlDataSource;
            gridmaxdata.DataBind();

            // Create SQLDataSource.
            SqlDataSource sqlDataSource2 = new SqlDataSource();
            sqlDataSource2.ID = "SqlDataSource12";
            this.Page.Controls.Add(sqlDataSource2);

            // Bind ConnectionString to SQLDataSource.
            sqlDataSource2.ConnectionString = connectionString;
            // Retrieve records with only 5 Columns from Employees table of NorthWind Database.
            sqlDataSource2.SelectCommand = "SELECT [date], [data] FROM [loc1] WHERE (([date] >= '" + combdatetime1.ToLongDateString() + "') AND ([date] < '" + combdatetime2.ToLongDateString() + "')) ORDER BY [data] DESC, [date] DESC";

            // Bind SQLDataSource to GridView after retrieving the records.
            gridcurdata.DataSource = sqlDataSource2;
            gridcurdata.DataBind();
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

remove the `%` in the format strings

if you need  allow single day then change below

```
"%d/MM/yyyy"
```

to

```
"d/MM/yyyy"
```

If the input can be multiple formats use below overload of `TryParseExact`

```
DateTime dateValue;    
var formatStrings = new string[] { "dd/MM/yyyy", "d/MM/yyyy", "dd/M/yyyy", "d/M/yyyy" };
    if (DateTime.TryParseExact(dt, formatStrings, txtStart1.Text, DateTimeStyles.None, out dateValue))
        startdate =dateValue;
```

when convert time input you can simply convert it as below

```
 Label4.Text = string.Format("{0}:00:00",txtEnd2.Text);
```

you can check the length and convert to int value for validate the input.

---

but I wonder why all these text boxes for get start date time and the end date time!
I would use Timepicker with jQuery UI Datepicker.

http://trentrichardson.com/examples/timepicker/

Comment: do i have to move % from all of the code or just several?? because i used the % to make sure that user who input single input (eg 1) would be still acceptable as a date/time.

Comment: i have try remove the % for all startdate and enddate but still to no avail. if i remove from the time %H, the application does not recognize it as datetime format for time.